# How to get the nodes most connected to a certain node and range them by the number of relations between them in Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node of the `:Context` type to which certain nodes with the `:Concept` type are connected.

My task is to

1) first obtain all the `:Concept` nodes connected to a certain `:Context` node

2) then obtain the `:TO` relations between them.

3) range those `:Concept` nodes I got based on the number of `:TO` relations between them and select the top 150.

Right now I'm using this:

```
MATCH (ctx:Context{uid:'a10f7970-1f88-11e9-9847-ebe68e1b5239'}) 
WITH ctx 
MATCH (ctx)<-[:AT]-(c1:Concept)-[rel:TO]->(c2:Concept)-[:AT]->(ctx) 
WITH DISTINCT ctx, c1, c2, count(rel) as relCount 
ORDER BY relCount DESC LIMIT 10 RETURN c1, c2;
```

But it just hangs my Neo4J database and there's no response... When I run it with `EXPLAIN`, however, I get this:

[image]
[image]

What could I fix?

Comment: Some further information may help: If you skip the count(rel) and ordering, does it return results? How many of each node and relationship are there? If you tack the word EXPLAIN to the start of the query, can you post a screenshot of what it looks like? What version of Neo are you using?

Comment: @Pablissimo I added the results of `EXPLAIN` above. There are possibly a few hundred nodes and maybe about 8000 relationships. I'm using 3.3.3. And no, if I skip `count(rel)` this doesn't change anything. The DB hangs.

Comment: Your query does not look like it should be hanging. Might be a bug. Can you try updating to 3.5.8?